# How does pip know about virtualenv and where to install packages

Tags: python, installation, pip, virtualenv

I am familiar with how a python virtualenv works and when we activate, it mainly modifies `VIRTUAL_ENV` and `PATH` variable. Primarily it adds the `bin` directory of virtualenv to system `PATH` and sets `VIRTUAL_ENV` to point to the virtual env root directory.

As an experiment I did this using virtualenv (version 1.11.6):

```
# Created two fresh virtual environments
virtualenv /tmp/env1
virtualenv /tmp/env2
echo $PATH
> SOME_PATH_VALUE

# Play with env1
source /tmp/env1/bin/activate
echo $PATH
> /tmp/env1/bin:SOME_PATH_VALUE
pip list
> pip, setuptools, wsgiref
pip install wget
> pip, setuptools, `wget`, wsgiref

# Obviously env2 has pip, setuptools and wsgiref only as of now
export PATH=/tmp/env2/bin:$PATH
pip list
> pip, setuptools, wsgiref
```

With my experiments it was solely depending on `PATH` variable for determining the installation path, but I am not sure if thats the whole picture. So the key questions are:

1. How does pip know where to install the requested package?
2. If my virtualenv is configured not to look for site-packages (ensured that the `no-global-site-packages.txt` file exists in correct location) and `PATH` variable is correctly set, but pip install still looks into system site-packages, then how to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtualenvs have the `pip` command installed in their `bin/` directories. By swapping out the `PATH` you are executing a different `pip` command each time.

The `bin/pip` script is tied to the `bin/python` executable for that virtual env, and in turn that `bin/python` executable is tied to the virtualenv; you don't *have* to use `source bin/activate` to be able to use a virtualenv, because just the `bin/python` executable has all the information it needs.

You can see this by looking at the [`sys.prefix` variable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.prefix):

```
$ virtualenv-2.7 /tmp/env1
New python executable in /tmp/env1/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in /tmp/env1/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
$ virtualenv-2.7 /tmp/env2
New python executable in /tmp/env2/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in /tmp/env2/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
$ env1/bin/python -c 'import sys; print sys.prefix'
/private/tmp/env1
$ env2/bin/python -c 'import sys; print sys.prefix'
/private/tmp/env2
```

Comment: Great! So that means every virtualenv installation has a different `bin/python` binary which intern has information hardcoded when we create the environment.